# Find The Lim $a_n$ When $a_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{6+a_n}$

Tags: calculus

Let there be $a_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{6+a_n}$, $a_1=3$

 
So the first elements are $a_1=3$,$a_2=1+\sqrt{6+3}=4$,$a_3=1+\sqrt{10}$,$a_4=1+\sqrt{6+1+\sqrt{10}}$.
With induction It is easy to see that the sequence monotonically increasing, What is left is to show that it as an upper bound.

How can I guess what is the limit (answer:10)?

Comment: Try to complete : "if there is a limit, then ...". Your turn, now

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici then there is an upper bound?

Comment: @gbox I think it is 4.192... and not 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use induction to show that the sequence is monotonically increasing, as you said, so I won't elaborate on that. For showing that it is bounded above, observe that $a_1<5$. Then if $a_n < 5$ for some $n\ge 1$,
$$ a_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{6+a_n}\le1+\sqrt{6+5}=1+\sqrt{11}<5,$$
so it follows by induction that $a_n<5$ for all $n$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists; call it $a$. Then solving $a=1+\sqrt{6+a}$ for $a$ we find that
$$a=\frac12(3\pm\sqrt{29}).$$
Since $a_1>0$ and $a_n$ is monotonically increasing, $a$ cannot be negative, so the correct answer is $\frac12(3+\sqrt{29})$.

Comment: As for how I came up with 5 for an upper bound - I just guessed, and it worked. To be more systematic about it, you could "work backwards" and solve $a=1+\sqrt{6+a}$, then use that value in your proof (although it is cleaner to just use a greater value like 5).

Comment: but in general I it is hard to have an assomption on the limit based on the first and second element.
What you are saying is because $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ differ in finite number I can treat them the same?

Comment: If $a_n\to a$, then $a_{n+1}\to a$ as well. That's why we can replace $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ by $a$ - but only after we prove that the limit exists!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the *possible* value of the limit verifies (why?)
$$a=1+\sqrt{6+a}$$
Relation between $a$ and upper bounds of the sequence?

Comment: If there is a limit so there is an upper bound, but what is the way to guess it is 10?

Comment: @gbox, the limit *is* an upper bound.

Comment: Thanks! for the correction

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving all such problems is the following: if the limit exists, say, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=L$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n+1}=L$. So letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ in your problem gives you an equation with $L$ on both sides which you need to solve.